# Importing notebook from Databricks into PowerBI

Tags: powerbi, databricks, databricks-sql

Is there easy way to import results of sql written in databricks notebook directly into powerbi ?

Comment: what about saving results as a table? Or create a view based on your query?

Answer (score 0):

You can use the Partner Connect feature from Databricks. In a few clicks, it will help you to connect Delta tables with Power BI.

---

If that doesn't help then, export the data as CSV and use that as source for PowerBI

Comment: See https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/databricks/integrations/bi/power-bi